# Selection of dropdown save

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I have one dropdownlist,it contains 3 items like open invoices,close invoices and all invoices.when select any one it should into array or arraylist.like if i select index 1 means it should save,then i select index 2 means it should save,again i select index 1 means it shouls save in to seperate index of arrat,not replace.Is it possible for array,for foreach or arraylist.I try arraylist

```
if (ddlTransaction.SelectedIndex < 3)
{
    list.Add(ddlTransaction.SelectedItem);
}
```

but it save only current selection of dropdown item save.

Answer (score 1):

Note sure if I understand your question but it seems like the issue is your not persisting the list after postback, try to use session in order to persist :

```
List<String> List = new List<String>();
if(Session["List"] != null)
{
List  = (List<String>)Session["List"];
}
if (ddlTransaction.SelectedIndex < 3)
{
    List.Add(ddlTransaction.SelectedValue);
    Session["List"] = List;
}
```